# Springboot Jboss system property issue

Tags: spring-boot, jboss

In our Springboot MVC project we need to get context path. The following code works fine if we use embedded tomcat. Otherwise if we deploy war file to jboss server, context path returns null.

I tried to add context-root property to jboss-web.xml but changed nothing. I also tried to add "server.servlet.contextPath" property to application.properties file but it doesn't work.

Spring boot version : 2.2.0.RELEASE

Code:

```
    @Configuration
public class EurekaClientConfigBeanListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {

   public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
    String pathValue = System.getProperty("server.servlet.contextPath");
   }
```